# Changing iframe URL to another protocol reloads the page, but not when fired from a timer

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, iframe

My theory is that later incarnations of Chrome@Android stops the behaviour below when not "user triggered".
*My question is if anyone has found a work around.*

---

Setting src with another schema on an `iframe` makes the device open an app.
Well.. it works for certain browsers@devices.

It has worked for "all" devices since a year but not since a while back.

It works when I trigger this event from a click like so:
(this works on "all" devices)

```
$("#myAnchor").click( function() {
    $("#myIframe").attr( 'src', 'schema://redirect=whatever' );
});
```

But not from a timer like so:
(i.e. this works on ie10metro@win8, safari@ios and opera@android but not chrome@android)

```
window.setTimeout( function() {
    $("#myIframe").attr( 'src', 'schema://redirect=whatever' );
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We stopped the latter from working in Chrome, it was at the time abused for redirecting to the playstore or other apps.  (note: I actually thought we stopped the former from working too).

The preferred solution is to use the intent Anchor syntax https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents